# Duplicates with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have been challenged with removing duplicates from a table with 250 million rows.

For ease of use, lets say we have three columns,

ACCOUNT, CHARGE_CODE, FILE_NAME

Now, the twist...

duplicate ACCOUNT and CHARGE_CODE combinations are allowed if the duplicate appears in the same FILE_NAME, but should be removed if the ACCOUNT and CHARGE_CODE combination exists exactly for another FILE_NAME.

I have tried ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) and get duplicates, but not duplicate "other file" duplicate I am after.

```
ACCOUNT   CODE    FILE_NAME
001       00001   A.TXT
001       00001   A.TXT
001       00001   A.TXT
001       00001   B.TXT
001       00001   C.TXT
```

The B.txt and C.txt would be subject for deletion.

I have tried ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) and get duplicates, but not the duplicate "other file duplicate" I am after.

This is full code I have tried but am not sure how to group the row_numbers for the same file

```
    SELECT TB1.[CLIENT_FACILITY_ID], TB1.[ACCOUNT], TB1.[CHARGE_DESC], TB1.[CHARGE_CODE], TB1.[CHARGE_TYPE], TB1.[BATCH_DATE], 
    TB1.[CHARGE_DATE], TB1.[CHARGE_QTY], TB1.[CHARGE_AMT], TB1.[HCPCS], TB1.[RC], TB1.[FILE_NAME], TB1.[MODIFIER], TB1.[POA], TB1.[POSTING_DATE], TB1.ROW_NUMBER
    FROM
    (SELECT [CLIENT_FACILITY_ID], [ACCOUNT], [CHARGE_DESC], [CHARGE_CODE], [CHARGE_TYPE], [BATCH_DATE], 
    [CHARGE_DATE], [CHARGE_QTY], [CHARGE_AMT], [HCPCS], [RC], [FILE_NAME], [MODIFIER], [POA], [POSTING_DATE],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CLIENT_FACILITY_ID], [ACCOUNT], [CHARGE_DESC], [CHARGE_CODE], [CHARGE_TYPE], [BATCH_DATE], 
    [CHARGE_DATE], [CHARGE_QTY], [CHARGE_AMT], [HCPCS], [RC], [MODIFIER], [POA], [POSTING_DATE], [FILE_NAME] 
    ORDER BY [CLIENT_FACILITY_ID], [ACCOUNT], [CHARGE_DESC], [CHARGE_CODE], [CHARGE_TYPE], [BATCH_DATE], 
    [CHARGE_DATE], [CHARGE_QTY], [CHARGE_AMT], [HCPCS], [RC], [MODIFIER], [POA], [POSTING_DATE]) ROW_NUMBER
    FROM DAT_CHARGES
    WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE 'O%') TB1
    WHERE TB1.ROW_NUMBER > 1
```

I need to be able to provide a listing of all rows that would be considered duplicated in this example.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the rows with the most values for `filename` (for a given group), you can use window functions to identify the duplicates:

```
select t.*
from (select dc.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by account, code order by cnt_acf desc, filename) as seqnum
      from (select dc.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by account, code, filename) as cnt_acf
            from dat_charges
           ) dc
     ) dc
where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.You present another obstacle I did not anticipate.   I will try your code and see the results.

Comment: While this works well, the client has abandoned the need for what they asked for.  I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions, with a CTE and `group by account, code, file_name` to get non duplicate filenames in each group:

```
with cte as (
  select account, code
  from dat_charges
  group by account, code
  having count(*) = 1
)
select d.account, d.code, d.file_name
from dat_charges d left join cte c
on c.account = d.account and c.code = d.code
where c.account is null
group by d.account, d.code, d.file_name
having count(*) = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=868ab34dddedbc8be17ef405481349db).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The client has completely changed their minds, but I do appreciate your response.